# URL's in Django

Tags: django, url, routes, indexing

I have a sort of general question. I am new to Django. The app I wanted to build is built, and it works fine. There are several tweaks. But I have sort of a conceptual question(I think). The app is basically like a wiki, so there is an article create/edit page, a page to view all articles and a login page. My question is this: I want an index page to load first that has nothing to do with the app. The index page will be more of an intro with a way into the app. Now, not sure if I'm framing this right, but are there html pages that can be served in django outside of the "app?" That is to say, URL's that get you to the logic of the app, but don't contain any app logic themselves?

Example: go to home.com. Click on an image, image takes you to that category, then from home/category.com you can view or create/edit article. The app that I have built really starts at the home/category/article level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the information on the intro page needs to be dynamic? And I mean anything - even if it shows the user name at the top right - then that information can change, and you can't just use simple html for that (meaning you probably want to use django for it).

But even if it is static - yeah, you can serve it separately - why would you?

If your entire app is built with Django, it's a lot easier to keep it that way. Just create a home function that returns a template and route it from `urls.py` to the right URL and that's it:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Why work harder to achieve something so simple?

Comment: Agreed. And I didn't even think about the simple dynamism of showing the logged in user. And you are right, it would be easier serve it from the app rather than static. Thanks.